# Simplifying small piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have

```
var index = link.attr('href');
index =index.replace("#",'');
```

and later in my code I use the "index" again

It feels like I could write this easier, but I don't know how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not in a single line

```
var index = link.attr("href").replace("#", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both operations on the same line:

```
var index = link.attr('href').replace("#", "");
```

The concept is called method chaining, check out a detailed post on the subject: http://schier.co/post/method-chaining-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use [function chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) here. Something like this:

```
var index = link.attr('href').replace("#",'');
```

The [`attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) actually returns the resulting attribute string itself. So you just call the [`replace()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the returned string value of `attr()`.

---

For example, if the `href` attribute's value is `http://google.com`, your code would evaluate to something like this:

```
var index = "http://google.com".replace("#",'');
```

To the JavaScript code, once it has extracted your `href` attribute, you're just executing a `replace()` on a string.